Difference in behavior between cURL and Invoke-WebRequest for Authorization headers
I'm encountering an issue when trying to make an API request using Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell, which works perfectly fine using curl. Specifically, the problem arises with the Authorization header.
Here is the curl command that works successfully (through Postman):
curl --location 'http://localhost:8000/api/books/v1/books/1' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'

However, when trying to do this using PowerShell with Invoke-WebRequest, the API responds with an error indicating that authentication credentials were not provided:
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8000/api/books/v1/books/1" -Method GET -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer xxx" }).Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

This results in the following error:
Invoke-WebRequest : {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
At line:1 char:2
+ (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8000/api/books/v1/books/1"  ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Additional info:

The Invoke-WebRequest was tried in PowerShell, while the curl command is from Postman. The request is actually executed in Postman and then I copied the curl command generated there.
I ensured that the header names are correctly cased "Authorization" .
I removed the -ContentType "application/json" header since it's a GET request.
Verified that the token is correctly copied without any hidden characters.

What are the differences in how curl and Invoke-WebRequest handle headers, particularly the Authorization header? Why does the API accept the request made with curl but reject the one made with Invoke-WebRequest? Is there any specific behavior or setting in Invoke-WebRequest that could cause this discrepancy?

'I removed the -ContentType "application/json" header since it's a GET request.' - that's not a safe assumption, lots of API middleware use the content-type request header as an output formatting indicator

Not an answer to your question, but I notice, you extract the content from the response right away. Since it seems you are not interested in the metadata from the response you may want to use Invoke-RestMethod. This Cmdlet will extract the content and will also deserialize the JSON into an PSCustomObject in a single go.

The default HTTP header are different depending on the programming language.  You need to add/modify the headers to get working. Try Postman which is very robust and adds missing headers. If Postman works than use Postman Control Panel to see all the http headers.  Tan modify your PS cmdlet to match the Postman Headers.

@TheBrickAdmin there is no difference between the command above and when I just use: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8000/api/books/v1/books/1" -Method GET -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer xxx"} . The error is still the same.

If you run a Man-In-The-Middle proxy like Fiddler on your workstation and direct the curl and Invoke-WebRequest http requests through that you'll be able to see exactly what each sends, and then compare headers. Although I'm not sure if / how that would work for localhost requests - can you trace the requests from the api's server-side to see what each is sending?
